# Outlook shared calendar is not syncing new events

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar

I have an Outlook calendar on my work computer which I just successfully shared with my personal Outlook account. However, updates are not pushed to the personal account.

When sharing, initially all events show up in my personal account, but if I add or change an event on my work computer, those changes are not reflected. I have even tried with a completely new account created from scratch, and it doesn't sync. Can anyone point me in the right direction with my troubleshooting?

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. **On my PC:** I created a new Microsoft account (with a new `outlook.com` email address) in a web browser.
2. **On my work PC:** In Outlook (for Windows) I right-click on the calendar, I select "Sharing Permissions..." and in those settings add my new `outlook.com` email. I select "Can View all details".
3. **On my PC:** In Outlook on the web, I accept the email invite. The Outlook calendar populates with all the entries from my work computer.
4. **On my work PC:** I change or add an event.
5. **On my PC:** No changes are reflected. I've tried a lot of things: reloading, logging out and in, restarting. And even with a brand new email account. All the same. So I believe it must have to do with some settings on my work computer.
   Any ideas where to look/what the problem could be?

(I'm especially confused as the calendar entries initially do get synced. Just no updates...)

**EDIT March 29, 2024:**

Reached out to the IT department of my company. Response was that my work "Outlook Calendar will not function as SYNCH only as VIEW".
I must admit that I'm not entirely convinced. If they would not want me to share the calendar outside the company then that option would be blocked or not even appear in the settings (like other options that are normally there which don't appear).
I still plan to reach out to Microsoft directly to see if there is any better explanation / workaround but any further insights here would also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that when you log in to Outlook.com and open another account's calendar, the calendar doesn't sync?

Comment: @Christy It's not only on outlook.com, same happens on mobile/desktop apps – I just used the example from opening outlook in the browser to make sure it wasn't any issue with the apps not syncing but indeed for some reason modifications don't get pushed to the synced calendar

Comment: Based on my test on Outlook.com, i reproduced your issue, it's suggested that you could contact the support of Outlook.com for more professional support.

Comment: @Christy, thanks for this, glad I'm not alone!  I will get in touch with support and report back